# Plotly - Histogram bins size to weeks

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I'm trying to plot a histogram with date data using plotly. I would like to plot it with bin sizes corresponding to weeks, and that doesn't seem to work. I searched for documentation about it but didn't find anything.

Here is the code I have. I tried (line 5): 'D7' and 'W1'. That doesn't work (plotly seems not to recognize argument, and set it to one bin per day). What's strange is that 'M1', 'M3' etc... seem to work

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Histogram(x=df.col, 
                                   xbins=dict(
                                       start='2018-01-01',
                                       end='2018-12-31',
                                       size='D7'), 
                                   autobinx=False)])
fig.update_layout(
    title=go.layout.Title(
        text="title",
        xref="paper",
        x=0.5
    ),
    xaxis_title_text='xaxis title',
    yaxis_title_text='yaxis title'
)


fig.show()
```

Would someone have any information about this problem ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a resampled data source and a bar plot is what you're really looking for:

**Plot:**

[image]

Here, the source data based on daily observations `DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', ... , '2020-07-18'],` have been resampled to show sum per week for a certain stock price.

**Code:**

```
# Imports
import pandas as pd
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
#from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot

# data, random sample to illustrate stocks
np.random.seed(12345)
rows = 200
x = pd.Series(np.random.randn(rows),index=pd.date_range('1/1/2020', periods=rows)).cumsum()
y = pd.Series(x-np.random.randn(rows)*5,index=pd.date_range('1/1/2020', periods=rows))
df = pd.concat([y,x], axis = 1)
df.columns = ['StockA', 'StockB']

# resample daily data to weekly sums
df2=df.reset_index()
df3=df2.resample('W-Mon', on='index').mean()

# build and show plotly plot
fig = go.Figure([go.Bar(x=df3.index, y=df3['StockA'])])
fig.show()
```

Let me know how this works for you.

Comment: yes, that works, but I was looking for a solution that would not need to work on the data, but rather just give another value to dict xbins. But thanks for your answer

Comment: @HuguesGALLIER That  approach does not exist at the moment.

Comment: @HuguesGALLIER Given that my suggestion seems to be the only existing working approach, would you consider marking it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 6):

`xbins.size` is specified in milliseconds by default. To get weekly bins, set `xbins.size` to `604800000` (7 days with 86,400,000 milliseconds each).

Plotly provides the format `xM` to get monthly bins because this use case requires more complicated calculations in the background, as monthly bins do not have a uniform size.